# How to find a class declaration from a parsed groovy script

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

**TL;DR: How can I access a class defined in a groovy script that is parsed dynamically?**

Let's say I have a groovy script like this:

```
def foo(){ print "foo" }

def bar(){ print "bar" }

class Baz {
    def waz(){
        print "Baz#waz"
    }
}
```

... and I can parse it out to a Script object like this:

```
Script myScript = new GroovyShell().parse(new File("my_script.groovy"))
```

Then I know I can access the functions:

```
myShell.foo()
myShell.bar()
```

But how can I access the `Baz` class declaration?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

by default groovyshell uses own classloader to load script and nested classes.

so, you could access it through classloader

```
def script = '''
def foo(){ print "foo" }

def bar(){ print "bar" }

class Baz {
    def waz(){
        print "Baz#waz"
    }
}
'''
def gshell = new GroovyShell()
Script myScript = gshell.parse(script)
myScript.foo()

println gshell.getClassLoader().loadClass('Baz')
```